# Failed to apply network settings - file /sbin/iptables doesn't exist for bluetooth xubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, bluetooth, iptables

After upgrading xubuntu 16.04 to 20.04, when I reboot I always have this popup : [image]

bluetooth works : I can send and receive files.

I've tried to reinstall iptables but nothing changed.

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: No changes after reinstallation iptables but thanks for your answer @N0rbert, I created the symlink /sbin/iptables. After reboot, the pop-up window has disappeared. Hope an update won't delete this symlink.